# Compile time Polymorphism and resolution of `this` keyword

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, overloading

I'm calling an overloaded method of some class ( `c.doSomething` ), from a class, and I'm passing the class instance as the argument.It is better explained using the following scenario:

```
public class A {

    protected int do(){
        C.doSomething(this);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class B extends A {

    public int doSomething(){
        do();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class C{
    public static function doSomething(B b){ System.out.println("b"); }
    public static function doSomething(A a){ System.out.println("a"); }

}
```

---

Now if I do something like the below in `main`, which of the `doSomething` methods will be called from `C`?

```
B b = new B();
b.doSomething();
```

Comment: Please post compiling code.

Comment: The easiest way to find out would be to just test it yourself.

Comment: What makes you think one of the methods of C should be invoked? And I do not see any overriding here.

Comment: I have updated the question and provided an answer. Please remove the Down Votes.

Comment: I'm lost in A's `do()` It calls `do` on `c` not `doSomething`. Is this a typo?

Answer (score 0):

This is rightfully called "compile time polymorphism" since `C.doSomething(A a)` is called and we are calling `C.doSomething` inside `A`. It is interesting to note that putting a `getClass()` inside `A.do` will yield `"B"` when `b.doSomething` is called.

Comment: This would be exactly what I expect because B is the runtime type.